# Python unit test SetupClass with variables from config file

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm currently trying to rework how we do unit testing of our code. For this we decided to go with an intermediate format of serialized test descriptions in xml. The general structure consisted of a Base class (derived from unittest.Testcase) and then classes per configuration (previously a bunch of python files in their own folders) that inherit from this Base Class.

We've changed the way we call the and discover the unit tests, but I'm having a problem with regards to the SetupClass method of unittest.

Previously, this method had been overwritten in the Base Class and it needed to be called with a number of variables distinct for each test case, which we did from the derived classes SetupClass methods (call to super(...).SetupClass(,vars...).

Now that we're trying to get rid of the python files that hold this configuration in rather verbose and hard to track/configure way, I've run into a problem.

Example of an xml config file:

```
<TestConfig>
  <Cases>
    <TestCase>
      <Name>Run Time</Name>
      <GUID>1234-5678</GUID>
      <Comparison>LessThan</Comparison>
      <Value>22</Value>
    </TestCase>
    <TestCase>
      <Name>Memory Usage</Name>
      <GUID>5678-1234</GUID>
      <Comparison>Equal</Comparison>
      <Value>150</Value>
    </TestCase>
  </Cases>
</TestConfig>
```

My current implementation of the Base Class:

```
class MyUnitTestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def SetupClass(self, var1, var2,...):
       some_internal_setup_stuff using var1 etc.
```

Now I'm searching for all the config files in my folder structure and using that list to try and setup a test suite of all the tests I want to run.

```
def parseTestSuite(cfg_files):
    all_suites = unittest.TestSuite()
    for cfg_file in cfg_files:
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        class MyUnitTestDerived(MyUnitTestBase):
            pass
        try:
            tree  = eTree.parse(cfg_file)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for section in root[0]:
                for item in section:
                    test_item = TestItem() #parsing helper
                    test_item.parse_from_xml(item) #my parsing of the settings
                    test_name = 'test_%s' % (test_item.name).replace(" ","_")
                    setattr(MyUnitTestDerived, test_name, test_generator(test_item.comparison, test_item.exp_value,test_item.comp_value))
                suite.addTests(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyUnitTestDerived))
        except:
            raise
        all_suites.addTests(suite)
    return all_suites
```

and to help with the test method generation:

```
def test_generator(comparison, exp_value, comp_value):
    if comparison=="LessThan":
        def test(self):
            self.assertLessEqual(exp_value, comp_value)
    elsif comparison=="Equal":
        def test(self):
            self.assertEqual(exp_value, comp_value)
    elif xxx:
        etc...
    return test
```

The detection seems to work, as does the parsing and the filling of the suite with the correct tests seems to work as well.
What I'm struggling with is however that I need to call the setupClass method with variables, whereas here I cannot. I haven't figured out yet where I would add this and how I could make this work again with the old BaseClass implementation of it.

One thing I've tried (and I'm sure I'm going to python-hell for this) is replacing the `pass` with:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(self, var1 = var1_from_conf, var2 = var2_from_conf, etc):
    return super(MyUnitTestDerived, self).setUpClass(var1 = var1_from_conf, var2 = var2_from_conf, etc)
```

in order to force default setup to use the variables from the config that are already known at that point in time, but it doesn't seem to even ever call this setUpClass (tried with debug print).

I'd appreciate any sort of help you can give me. I know it is quite a convoluted problem, but I've tried to break it down into as simple a case as I could.

Comment: I just want to point out to you that using XML for this poses one major issue - order of child elements does not matter in XML. When you send this XML file somewhere else and then de-serialize it your test cases will be in a seemingly random order. You'll need to add a "test ID" or something to each TestCase so that they can be sorted by that and then run in the correct order on the receiving end. As another alternative you can use a YAML file and then put the test cases in a list.

Comment: This is true but not a problem, since the order of the tests does not matter (within a config file). And I thought that unittest, in any case, does not promise to run the cases in order.